# Sending put using ajax in Spring

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, http-put

I am trying to send put to controller using ajax. here is my code:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var toUrl = '/users/' + $('#id').val() + '/profile';
        $.ajax({
            url: toUrl,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringfy({name: 'data'}),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});
```

and thats how i try to catch this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String updateProfileInfo(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody ProfileForm profileForm){

    System.out.println(profileForm.getName());
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    return null;
}
```

just want to display something to console to know that something happend and i don't know why this isn't working.

Ofc i have mapping on class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}/profile")
public class ProfileController {
```

Comment: What's the problem?  The problem isn't so clear.

Comment: Yeah, tell us; I managed to recreate an (almost) identical situation and it works fine. Tips: try to narrow down cause of the failure (does the request even reach `DispatcherServlet`?), what (if any) HTTP error codes do you get? is there anything relevant in Spring logs? (if not: increase logger level even to TRACE)

Comment: It is not working. After send put nothing is displayed on console. I dont know why. Everything looks fine for me but it isn`t working. PUT request is never mapped

Comment: problem is that i don't even know how to check any logs. Can't find anything that would show me what is happening

Comment: Do i need to set whole url? with http://.....??

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the whole url. Is there anything in your browser console? Also, could you post the request headers?

Comment: Is **JSON.stringfy** is a typo? (just in case: should be "stringify")

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start the server in debug mode , set the breakpoint at appropriate place and see if it hits the updateProfileInfo method.  You need to hit `http://APPLICATION_NAME/users/ID/profile` .

If you use firfox install firebug plug-in and check request/response.